# After creating Bottom Navigation View Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I created my Bottom Navigation View which contains my 3 top locations on my note app 1. View notes 2. Create notes 3. Settings since each location are created as a fragment I was wondering do I have to create activities for each of these locations of can I just run them as fragments.

Comment: Can't really contribute to your question. Nevertheless I didn't want to just go on without saying "Selam" to a habesha.

Comment: `BottomNavigation` by default Works with fragments if you need to make the content change and stick `BottomNavigation` at the bottom, you can also make it work with Activities but this is not recommended , so it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Please edit your question, read [ask] and add code and details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering do I have to create activities for each of these locations of can I just run them as fragments.

No you do not have to create activities. Yes you can just run them as fragments.

Answer (score 0):

**You do not have to create all the activities. just create one activity where you take bottomNavigationView and than take all other fragments. It works easily.

Hope it will work for you....!**